# Android display JSONArray in Listview with data from API (website)

Tags: android, json, api, listview

I am very new to Android and have a task set to display a list of Genres from an API 
I have no clue as to what is going on. I successfully implemented a normal listview with hardcoded data. But now I need to use REST services and connect to the net and display data in a listview.

My XML is very basic, just a listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/lstView"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

After that, I have my class. I have two (2) errors currently. The first is trying to get the string returned from the API into a JSONArray. The second just decided to occur, by sayuing the symbol R cannot be resolved. No idea how that happened.

Anyway, here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Genre extends Activity {
    ListView listView;
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "HttpExample";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstView);

       ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        String result=null;
      try {
             result = downloadUrl();
        }catch(IOException e)
        {}

        ArrayList<String> lstData = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray jarray = (JSONObject)result; //ERROR HERE
        try {
            if (jarray != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    lstData.add(jarray.get(i).toString());
                }
            }
        }catch(JSONException j)
        {}

       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, lstData);

       listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                int itemPosition = position;

                String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position :" + itemPosition + " ListItem :" + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private String downloadUrl() throws IOException{
        InputStream is = null;

        int len = 500;

        try{
            URL url = new URL("website here");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"The response is: " + response);
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
            return contentAsString;
        }finally{
            if(is != null){
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException{
        Reader reader = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        char[] buffer = new char[len];
        reader.read(buffer);
        return new String(buffer);
    }
}
```

I have commented the section that gives me errors. The R symbol though is another story. If I could just get the app to successfully return and convert the JSONArray that would be great.

I have copied and pasted most, if not all, the code from various websites and StackOverflow itself looking for an answer.

The JSON data I am getting:

> {"genres":[{"id":28,"name":"Action"},{"id":12,"name":"Adventure"},{"id":16,"name":"Animation"},{"id":35,"name":"Comedy"},{"id":80,"name":"Crime"},{"id":99,"name":"Documentary"},{"id":18,"name":"Drama"},{"id":10751,"name":"Family"},{"id":14,"name":"Fantasy"},{"id":10769,"name":"Foreign"},{"id":36,"name":"History"},{"id":27,"name":"Horror"},{"id":10402,"name":"Music"},{"id":9648,"name":"Mystery"},{"id":10749,"name":"Romance"},{"id":878,"name":"Science Fiction"},{"id":10770,"name":"TV Movie"},{"id":53,"name":"Thriller"},{"id":10752,"name":"War"},{"id":37,"name":"Western"}]}

I would like to display the name for now, but I can go for both ID and name.
Help would be much appreciated. Thank you
Also, please comment if you need more data

Comment: only names in list view?

Comment: `JSONArray jarray = (JSONObject)result; //ERROR HERE` , really ?

Comment: How can you typecasting your json result to jsonobject and then assigning it to jsonarray

Comment: go through this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: JSON using Retrofit2 example https://www.freakyjolly.com/create-multiple-columns-listview-from-json-data-using-retrofit2-in-android-example/

Answer (score 1):

Your result is a Json string, so you need to get JSONArray like this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray jarray = obj.getJSONArray("genres");
```

Remember to catch exception.

Comment: still has the error cannot cast java.lang.String to org.json.JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

Complete tutorial https://www.freakyjolly.com/create-multiple-columns-listview-from-json-data-using-retrofit2-in-android-example/

example using **JSON**

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "phone": "+9178XXXX66",
      "name": "Olivia"
    },
    {
      "phone": "+9178XXXX66",
      "name": "Isla"
    },
    {
      "phone": "+9178XXXX66",
      "name": "Emily"
    },
    {
      "phone": "+9178XXXX66",
      "name": "Amelia"
    },
    {
      "phone": "+9178XXXX66",
      "name": "Sophia"
    }],
  "statusCode": "1",
  "count": "2"
}
```

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listShowJSONData"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="398dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
```

**json_data_list.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userDetails"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userStatus"
    android:layout_width="83dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Now Custom **BaseAdapter** (CustomListAdapter)

```
...
...
@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if(view==null)
    {
        view= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.json_data_list,viewGroup,false);
    }

    TextView mUserDetails = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userDetails);
    TextView mUserStatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userStatus);


    Object getrow = this.users.get(i);
    LinkedTreeMap<Object,Object> rowmap = (LinkedTreeMap) getrow;
    String name = rowmap.get("name").toString();
    String phone = rowmap.get("phone").toString();

    mUserDetails.setText(name);
    mUserStatus.setText(phone);

    return view;
}
...
...
```

For RetroFit2 usage and complete code see source link